# Error while installing WhiteSur GTK theme

Tags: command-line, apt, themes, gtk

When installing WhiteSur GTK theme through this [tutorial video at (5:56)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXIb-1_H-mA&ab_channel=LinuxScoop)
Please help

```
  =========== ERROR LOG ===========
  >>> W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
  >>> E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
  >>> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
  >>> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
  
  =========== ERROR INFO ==========
  FOUND  :
    >>> install.sh
    >>> lib-core.sh
    >>> lib-install.sh at 131;137
  SNIPPET:
    >>> apt update -y
  TRACE  :
    >>> signal_error
    >>> prepare_install_apt_packages
    >>> install_theme_deps
    >>> install_themes
    >>> main
  
  =========== SYSTEM INFO =========
  DISTRO : ubuntu;debian;22.04
  SUDO   : no
  GNOME  : 42-0
  REPO   : 2022-06-03T19:41:53+0530

  HINT: You can run: 'sudo apt install sassc libglib2.0-dev libxml2-utils' on ubuntu 18.04 or 'sudo apt install sassc libglib2.0-dev-bin' on ubuntu >= 20.04 

  HINT: You can google or report to us the info above 

  https://github.com/vinceliuice/WhiteSur-gtk-theme/issues
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the hint given by the error message?

```
sudo apt install sassc libglib2.0-dev libxml2-utils
```

Run that in the terminal and try executing the script again.

Comment: Thanks that did work.
But I'm stuck with another issue. While downloading reversal icons, I extracted the file and opened it in the terminal.
Typed ls, then next line ./install.sh -red

This is where the error occurs.
Terminal:
Installing '/home/iam_mystic/.local/share/icons/Reversal-red'...
cp: cannot stat '/home/iam_mystic/Downloads/Ubuntu': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Wallpaper/Reversal-icon-theme-master/COPYING': No such file or directory
.
.
.
.

Comment: You can answer that question in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1415025/reversal-icons-installation-error-cpcannot-stat

Comment: It looks like It's trying to copy some files from the `Ubuntu` directory inside your `Downloads` directory (`/home/iam_mystic/Downloads/Ubuntu`). Have you deleted or moved some files/directories between the first and current try of running the script?
Something is missing.
Maybe try to re-download all the data to make sure nothing is missing.